# Onsen UI Sliding Menu : custom parameters with SetMainPage?

Tags: onsen-ui

Is there a way to set parameters for the next page when calling SetMainPage() on sliding menu ?

Something similar to :

```
myNavigator.pushPage("page2.html", { param1: "value1", param2: "value2" });
```

but using

```
myMenu.setMainPage(...);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE**:
I think there is a way to achieve what you want like this:

```
<body ng-controller="ctrl">
<ons-sliding-menu
menu-page="menu.html" main-page="page1.html" side="left"
var="menu" type="reveal" max-slide-distance="260px" swipeable="true">
```

```
<ons-template id="menu.html">
<ons-list>
<ons-list-item modifier="chevron" ng-click="setParam('option1');">
  page1
</ons-list-item>
<ons-list-item modifier="chevron" ng-click="setParam('option2');">
  page2
</ons-list-item>   
</ons-list>
</ons-template>
</body>
```

And in javascript:

```
var module = angular.module('app', ['onsen']);
var params = {msg:""};//define a global object

module.controller('ctrl', function($scope){
  $scope.setParam = function (msg) {
      params.msg = msg;//set the options you want in the object
      menu.setMainPage('page1.html', {closeMenu: true});//change the page
  }
});
module.controller("page1ctrl" function($scope){
   var options = params.msg; // this will give you the options you set earlier
});
```

Comment: Ok but how do I retrieve them ? Is there a way like $scope.myNavigator.getCurrentPage().options.param1 ?

Comment: I edited my answer. It seems that there is no option for that now

Comment: Ok, thank you for your help. Such a functionnality could be really useful.

Comment: I changed my answer. This approach can give what you want

Answer (score 0):

The documentation is misleading in this regard. It actually only accepts the closeMenu and callback parameters, not 'custom' as the example indicates. The use of param1 as a parameter example is misleading.